# unable to create docker image using git bash

Tags: dockerfile, git-bash

Unable to create docker image using git bash (windows 10)
created following Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:sid
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install nano
CMD ["bin/nano", "/tmp/notes"]
```

$ docker build -t example .

Get Error:

```
$ docker build -t example .
[+] Building 0.0s (3/3) FINISHED
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                  
=> => transferring dockerfile: 31B                                                                                
=> [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  
=> => transferring context: 2B                                                                                           

=> ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:sid                                             
------
> [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:sid:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to authorize: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to fetch oauth token: Get https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fdebian%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: dial tcp 3.211.199.249:443: i/o timeout
```

- steps tried: restart terminal, tried on cmd, restart docker desktop -
  no go

please advise, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error mentions `failed to fetch oauth token`
Have you tried to run

```sh
docker login
```

in your terminal prior to running the build command?

Comment: thanks for your response
$ docker login --username=<my_username>
Password:
Login Succeeded

It's still the same

Comment: What happens next when you run the `docker build -t example .` command?

Comment: I get the same error as mentioned in the question, 
=> ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/example/nanoer:latest

Comment: Are you _certain_ it is the same error?  The error you've put in the question reads `ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:sid `...  Is the entire error message present in the question?  
The final line gives more details... Are the details for the error with `nanoer:latest` the same as the ones for `debian:sid`?

Comment: sorry, I was trying to edit Dockerfile
`=> ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:sid
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to authorize: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to fetch oauth token:`

I get the same error

Comment: Does this command `docker pull debian:sid` returns the same error?

Comment: `docker pull debian:sid
sid: Pulling from library/debian
Pull complete
Status: Downloaded newer image for debian:sid
docker.io/library/debian:sid`

Comment: And now the `docker build -t example .` cammnd still fails?

Comment: it works now! - thanks much for following up with me, Appreciate it :)